# how to check check box when it have a value

Tags: jquery

this is the html

```
<div class="form-field"><input name="category" id="library_category" type="radio" value="Engineering" class="form-radio" required="required"/> Engineering</div>
```

Management

 Medical

 Education

 Agriculture

this is the jquery

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        $('#library_category').val(obj.library_category);
        $('#library_type').val(obj.library_type);
        $('#library_attention').val(obj.library_attention);

        $('#library_category1').prop("checked", true);
});}
```

Comment: $('#library_type') should be $('#library_category') ????

Comment: This is a radio button, not a checkbox. And what do you achive exactly? Why do not check it when add the value? Check, what is the value of it by `$('#library_category').val()`

Answer (score 0):

If i get your question right, you can check a checkbox this way:

```
$('#library_category').prop("checked", true);
```

or

```
$('#library_category').val(obj.library_category).prop("checked", true);
```

Not the best way, but that should work (after you put the value in the input):

```
    $('.form-radio').each(function(){
        if($(this).val() == obj.library_category){
            $(this).prop("checked", true);
        }
    });
```

Comment: sorry twain but it select first radio of the same id i want to check only that who have the value assign by jquery

Comment: an id should only exist once.. ;) if you have more inputs use a class. to help you please add some more of your code

Comment: plz check twain i updated my question with more code

Comment: i want to select only one radio that got the values from db and assighn by jquery